# How to get the latest commits from Parent to Child after Merging in TFS

Tags: tfs

In TFS, I have made a branch from a parent repository some days back and started working on the child as base. During these period, another team made some significant changes in the parent branch and committed yesterday. I have to find a way to get all the change sets from the parent in my branch with out losing my changes. If somebody have any idea, please share

Comment: Merge parent to child as usually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply merge from parent to branch. If there is conflicts, you can compare the files and resolve the conflicts manually. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341461(v=expression.40).aspx